# Getting KML from blob file of Oracle using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, kml, cursor, oracle-dbms

How do I get a kml which is stored in a blob file of oracle using ArcPy?

i try get data or kml files contains in a database oracle  in a field of a table, using cursors options  of arcpy.

```
import arcpy, os
from arcpy import env
source =r'C:\connectionFiles\file.sde\tableoracle'
cursor = arcpy.SearchCursor(source)
```

The conection works correctly,  but the cursors do not work well for this type of information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to try the [`cx_Oracle`](http://cx-oracle.sourceforge.net/) package. From this [Esri KB article](http://support.esri.com/cn/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/40598):

```
import cx_Oracle

connection = cx_Oracle.connect('sde/sde@orcl')
cursor = connection.cursor()
querystring = "select * from table"
cursor.execute(querystring)
```

Above untested, as I don't have a Oracle instance to test against.